# How do I transform between datetimes and chart coordinates in Highcharts Renderer?

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts scatter plot with a datetime x axis. The x values are all in the past. The y coordinates are positive integers, typically in the range 100..10k. I want to draw lines from the imaginary point (tomorrow, 0) back to some of the data points.

The Renderer's path command looks to take absolute coordinates in chart space. How do I transform the point (tomorrow,0) into those absolute coordinates?

Also, assume the data was from 1995..2005. The default auto-scaling of Highcharts would make tomorrow be off the chart to the right. What will happen when drawing the path? Will the chart remain the same scale and the line be clipped at the right-hand edge? (That would be OK). Would the chart be redrawn with a new scale so that the x axis covered the whole span from 1995 to tomorrow? Something else?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Found it. There is a translate() function to do the conversion. See the Highcharts support forum thread at highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=9404.

Answer (score 4):

Found it. There is a `translate()` function to do the conversion. See the [Highcharts support forum thread](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=9404) for info on the function.

Answer (score 2):

Use Axis.[toPixels()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels%28%29) and Axis.[toValue()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toValue%28%29)